# Updating react state with GraphQL queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to update state with data collected from a GraphQL query.
I've tried to do it similarly to the official tutorial at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/ under the headline "Executing queries manually".

```
export default function SearchField() {
    const [
        searchInput,
        setSearchInput
    ] = useState('');
    const [
        drinks,
        setDrinks
    ] = useState(null);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        getDrinks({ variables: { cocktailName: searchInput } });
    };

    const [
        getDrinks,
        { loading, data }
    ] = useLazyQuery(MULTIPLE_COCKTAILS_BY_NAME_QUERY);

    if (loading)
        return (
            <div className="justify-content-center">
                <p>Loading ...</p>
            </div>
        );

    if (data && data.multipleCocktailsByName) {
        setDrinks(data.multipleCocktailsByName);
    }

    return (...)
```

The last section before return makes the component crash with "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." If I instead try updating the state in the handleSubmit like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        getDrinks({ variables: { cocktailName: searchInput } });
        setDrinks(data.multipleCocktailsByName);
    };
```

then I get the error "Cannot read property 'multipleCocktailsByName' of undefined". I still manage to render data conditionally from the query, but handling state is troublesome. I'd really appreciate help with getting this to work.

Comment: `useLazyQuery` should not be used unless you need to execute a query in response to a user action (like a click). Don't reinvent the wheel by managing the state yourself -- use `useQuery` instead which already exposes the data as state, in addition to loading and error state.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Daniel! I omitted the return section of the function to make the question more readable. However, in this case I want to use the query at the push of a button, so the lazyQuery seemed like the right choice.

Comment: You should use the `data` provided by the hook. You might be able to stuff it into component state using `useEffect` as suggested in one of the answers but this unnecessarily complicates your code.

Comment: @ZeGeR I updated my answer (now that I have access to a desktop) - it may help.

Answer (score 2):

in:

```
 if (data && data.multipleCocktailsByName) {
        setDrinks(data.multipleCocktailsByName);
 }
```

once you've successfully run the query and data is populated, you're stuck in an infinite loop setting drinks to that value.

You could either just use data as your component state (forget about drinks) and do:

```
if (loading) { ... } // render loading UI
if (error) { ... } // I suggest adding this so you can better debug.
if (data) { ... } // do what you intended to do with drinks but calling data.multipleCocktailsByName.
```

alternatively you could use a useEffect hook on "data" that would set the drinks state, but that seems unnecessary.

I should add, your second example fails because the calls are asynchronous, so data will not be what you expect it to be immediately after you make the call. that is why, if you want to have a drinks state you would use a use effect hook like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (data && data.multipleCocktailsByName) {
   setDrinks(data.multipleCocktailsByName
   }
},[data, setDrinks])
```

then drinks would be set only when data changes and contains a value.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried the useEffect solution you suggested but unfortunately it leads to another error. "React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks". I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: move your useEffect hook to the top of the component, you probably have an return statement inside a conditional somewhere before your useEffect, which means it's only conditionally called when your previous if statement is not true. in general, always put your hooks in the beginning of your components before you run any logic. You can read more about the rules here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation Feel free to paste your component code here to make sure that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current component is that the `if` statement (just before the `return`) will meet the criteria and update the state on every render (once the form is submitted and `useQuery` is executed - as in `data` now has values).

Since you are lazily loading the data anyway, you only need to update the component's state when the form is submitted. Moving the `if` statement to the `handleSubmit` function should resolve your issue, and negate the need for any side effects (`useEffect`).

I used `async/await` on the `handleSubmit` function, to ensure the query has completed prior to the state being updated.

```
export default function SearchField() {
    const [
        searchInput,
        setSearchInput
    ] = useState('');
    const [
        drinks,
        setDrinks
    ] = useState(null);
    const [
        getDrinks,
        { loading, data }
    ] = useLazyQuery(MULTIPLE_COCKTAILS_BY_NAME_QUERY);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await getDrinks({ variables: { cocktailName: searchInput } });
        if (data && data.multipleCocktailsByName) {
          setDrinks(data.multipleCocktailsByName);
        }
    };

    if (loading)
        return (
            <div className="justify-content-center">
                <p>Loading ...</p>
            </div>
        );

    return (...)
```

Something to consider down the track, is whether or not you actually need the `drinks` state variable at all? If you check the `useQuery` and `useLazyQuery` examples from Apollo, you will note that they generally just use the `data` variable directly in the return statement's JSX.

Usually this involves some conditional rendering, although that is common in a react component. If your not using `drinks` anywhere other than in the return statement, consider refactoring to take out the `useState` call and save yourself a re-render or two.